# <CefCompletionCallback> is not defined in C++

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

in my CEF i get the error CefCompletionCallback is not defined. 
Everything else seems to work.
For example inside the cef_cookie.h

```
  static CefRefPtr<CefCookieManager> GetGlobalManager(
      CefRefPtr<CefCompletionCallback> callback);
```

he says it says that the Identifier CefCompletionCallback is not defined.
I hope anyone can help me.